# Oracle Apex Security Cross Origin Resource Sharing(CORS)

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1, oracle-apex-18.2

Can someone explain/help where these Oracle Apex Security settings can be configure? Oracle Apex version is 21.1

[image]

Answer (score 2):

These settings are not configured within APEX, but within the web server that is running ORDS.

For example, if you are using Tomcat, all of the `Access-Control-*` headers are configured using the [CORS filter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter) and the `Strict-Transport-Security` header is configured using the [HTTP Header Security Filter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/filter.html#HTTP_Header_Security_Filter).

If you are using Weblogic or ORDS standalone, you will need to look at the documentation for those web servers to make the proper configurations.

Comment: Is this different from Shared Component - Security - HTTP Response headers?

Comment: That section seems to only have the ability to add additional headers, not remove or modify existing headers

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am using Apex with Autonomous DB. Will that configuration also applied?